# Airflow standalone command results in sqlite error

Tags: python, sqlite, airflow

I installed airflow using WSL in conda environment with python version 3.11. I followed the exact instructions written in airflow documentation:
[text](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start.html)

Once the installation completed, i ran **airflow standalone** command however even though it worked and I was able to see airflow UI login page via localhost, I noticed that logs contained error messages that seemed to be omitted. I stopped the standalone process and looked into it and the error was related to one of the tables that were trying to be selected but since it did not exiss, it resulted in error. I tried to uninstall airflow and install it again but this time the airflow standlone command did not even succeed and I faced the same error below:
(P.S. I also consulted buddy chatGPT but it did not seem to know what's up either)

````
airflow standalone
standalone | Starting Airflow Standalone
standalone | Checking database is initialized
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 10b52ebd31f7 -> 88344c1d9134, Drop unused TI index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1910, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 736, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: dag_run.clear_number

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 57, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_config.py", line 49, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 53, in entrypoint
    StandaloneCommand().run()
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/providers_configuration_loader.py", line 55, in wrapped_function
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 69, in run
    self.initialize_database()
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 179, in initialize_database
    db.initdb()
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 79, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 731, in initdb
    upgradedb(session=session)
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 1632, in upgradedb
    _reserialize_dags(session=session)
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 877, in _reserialize_dags
    dagbag.sync_to_db(session=session)
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 685, in sync_to_db
    import_errors = DagBag._sync_to_db(dags=self.dags, processor_subdir=processor_subdir, session=session)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 657, in _sync_to_db
    for attempt in run_with_db_retries(logger=log):
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 347, in __iter__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 325, in iter
    raise retry_exc.reraise()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 158, in reraise
    raise self.last_attempt.result()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 673, in _sync_to_db
    DAG.bulk_write_to_db(dags.values(), processor_subdir=processor_subdir, session=session)
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 3076, in bulk_write_to_db
    last_automated_runs = session.scalars(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1778, in scalars
    return self.execute(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1717, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1710, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 334, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1577, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1953, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2134, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1910, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/aezakme/miniconda3/envs/airflow_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 736, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: dag_run.clear_number
[SQL: SELECT dag_run.state, dag_run.id, dag_run.dag_id, dag_run.queued_at, dag_run.execution_date, dag_run.start_date, dag_run.end_date, dag_run.run_id, dag_run.creating_job_id, dag_run.external_trigger, dag_run.run_type, dag_run.conf, dag_run.data_interval_start, dag_run.data_interval_end, dag_run.last_scheduling_decision, dag_run.dag_hash, dag_run.log_template_id, dag_run.updated_at, dag_run.clear_number
FROM dag_run, (SELECT dag_run.dag_id AS dag_id, max(dag_run.execution_date) AS max_execution_date
FROM dag_run
WHERE dag_run.dag_id IN (SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT 1) WHERE 1!=1) AND (dag_run.run_type = ? OR dag_run.run_type = ?) GROUP BY dag_run.dag_id) AS anon_1
WHERE dag_run.dag_id = anon_1.dag_id AND dag_run.execution_date = anon_1.max_execution_date]
[parameters: (<DagRunType.BACKFILL_JOB: 'backfill'>, <DagRunType.SCHEDULED: 'scheduled'>)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)```


I have also tried to upgrade db based on chatGPT suggestions but nothing seem to work
````